# Как сделать временный мут? чтобы были часы минуты дни и т.д

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

У меня есть свой код на мут, и я хочу чтобы можно было писать sv!mute @чел 1h тест или же дни, но не знаю как сделать, помогите пожалуйста

````
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member, time: int, reason):
    channel = bot.get_channel(935828431038464000)
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Вы получили мут на сервере SVELL COMMUNITY по причине {reason} на {time} минут.")
    await user.send(embed=embed)
    role = user.guild.get_role(938090832794378260) # айди роли которую будет получать юзер
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{user} получил мут на {time} минут по причине: {reason} <:diz:938316834980126800>')
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await user.move_to(None)
    await asyncio.sleep(time * 60)
    await user.remove_roles(role)
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функцию `timeout()`

```py
import datetime
 
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member, time: int, *, reason):
    channel = bot.get_channel(935828431038464000)
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Вы получили мут на сервере SVELL COMMUNITY по причине {reason} на {time} минут.")
    await user.send(embed=embed)
    role = user.guild.get_role(938090832794378260) # айди роли которую будет получать юзер
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{user} получил мут на {time} минут по причине: {reason} <:diz:938316834980126800>')
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await user.timeout(until=datetime.datetime(hour=time), reason=reason)
```

В моём коде вы используете переменную `time` для обозначения кол-ва часов тайм-аута. Не забудьте перед использованием кода импортировать модуль `datetime`